multi image figure - 3 images same size and 1 image different on a single figure
Currently, I am trying to form a figure with multiple images (see the attached image). Easily, I was able to make the part with the first three images but I couldn't add the forth image which is the legend, in the way that I showed in the attached image.
Could you help?


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/image1.png}
\caption{image 1}
\label{image 1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/image2.png}
\caption{image 2}
\label{image 2}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/image3.png}
\caption{image 3}
\label{image 3}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Multiple images}
\label{Multiple images}
\end{figure}



Welcome to TeX.SE. Please make a habit of adding MWE when posting questions on this site.

In order to move content below, you have to add an empty line or precede such content with \par, which is equivalent to the empty line. Additionally, if you want to control vertical space, you can change \parskip inside the figure environment. See example below.
The full example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

% \usepackage{showframe}
% \renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}
% \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{blue}}


\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]

\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}%
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}%
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image}
        \caption{image 1}
        \label{image 1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image}
        \caption{image 2}
        \label{image 2}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics{example-image}
        \caption{image 3}
        \label{image 3}
    \end{subfigure}

    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth, height=1cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Multiple images}
    \label{Multiple images}
\end{figure}

\kant[1][3]
\end{document}



EDIT. A few remarks

You don't need \centering inside each subfigure env. because images span the whole width of their parenting box.
The line of \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth} sets width of every following image, so it does not have to be repeated.
While in this case it visually does not make difference, beware a new line adds an empty horizontal space, unless you end the previous line with %

To elaborate on the last point, consider again your example:
\begin{...}
...
\end{...} <--- empty horizontal space 
\hfill
\begin{...}
...
\end{...}

LateX adds space between the first and the second env. then use \hfill. So everything is aligned as expected. However, let's say you want to stick two boxes together. The following code would leave an empty space between them
\begin{...}
...
\end{...} 
\begin{...}
...
\end{...}

while this code would not
\begin{...}
...
\end{...}% <--- no empty space added
\begin{...}
...
\end{...}

Also, parameter-less macros, s.a. \hfill, \cetering consume spaces, so the above % is not required. On the other hand, if you want to force a space after such macro, add empty braces: {}, e.g. \mymacro{} instead of \mymacro.

Awesome, now I will try. I don't have any hesitation about it, thanks to your clear and extensive answer.
